# Poisson distribution and probability distributions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ has the $\mathrm{Poisson}(5)$ distribution considered earlier.

Then $P(X \in A) = \sum_{j\in A} \frac{e^{-5}5^j}{j!}$, which implies that $L(X) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \left(\frac{e^{-5}5^j}{j!}\right)\delta_j$, a convex combination of point masses. The following propostion shows that we have $E(f(X)) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{f(j)e^{-5}5^j}{j!}$ for any function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

**Prop.** Suppose $\mu = \sum_i \beta \mu_I$ where $\{\mu_i\}$ are probability distributions, and $\{\beta_i\}$ are non-negative constants (summing to 1, if we want $\mu$ to also be a probability distribution). Then for Borel-measurable functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$$\int fd\mu = \sum_i \beta_i \int f \, d\mu_i,$$

provided either side is well-defined.

Using this proposition:

Let $X \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(5)$.

(a) compute **E**$(X)$ and **Var**$(X)$.

(b) compute **E**$(3^X)$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\mathbb E(f(X) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{f(j)e^{-5}5^j}{j!}$.  It's not correct without "$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^\infty$".

Comment: good catch, thanks

Comment: Why did you create this exact duplicate of the question here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250413/poisson-distribution-and-probability-of-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three answers are $E[X]=\lambda$, $E[X^2]=\lambda+\lambda^2$ (from the previous two, you could compute the variance) and $E[\exp(3X)]=\exp(\lambda(e^3-1))$. As a hint, the major tool here is to use Taylor series expansion for the exponential function.

I noticed there was an edit with a new question (or I misread the previous one). The answer for  $E[3^X]$ is $\exp(2 \lambda)$.

---

I will give as an example how to compute $E[3^X]$. Writing the formula for the expectation
\begin{eqnarray*}
  E \left[ 3^X \right] & = & \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 3^k P \left[ X = k
  \right]\\
  & = & \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 3^k \mathrm{e}^{- \lambda}
  \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\\
  & = & \mathrm{e}^{- \lambda} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( 3 \lambda
  \right)^k}{k!}\\
  & = & \mathrm{e}^{- \lambda} \underbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(
  3 \lambda \right)^k}{k!}}_{= \mathrm{e}^{3 \lambda}}\\
  & = & \mathrm{e}^{2 \lambda}
\end{eqnarray*}

You see that the main tool here was the expansion of $\exp(3 \lambda)$.

Comment: Let me know if the hint is clear or sufficient.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused as to how to initially approach the problem.  The book we have isn't the best in describing how to approach the exercises.

Comment: Ok, I solved when of the examples in full. Please see the edit above.